I can't fix bean problem in springboot and mybatis project
Invalid bean definition error
I tried many different ways to solve it but I can't figure out.

I checked version of springboot and mybatis
I checked @ComponentScan and @MapperScan annotations
I checked Dto
I checked Mapper with annotation
I checked Sql.xml file

Can anyone help with it?
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.jake", "data.*"})
@MapperScan({"data.mapper"})
public class JakeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JakeApplication.class, args);
    }

}

package data.controller;

import data.dto.MemberDto;
import data.service.MemberService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MemberController {
    MemberService memberService;

    @PostMapping("/member/insert")
    public void insert(@RequestBody MemberDto dto)
    {
        memberService.insertMember(dto);
    }
}

package data.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.Alias;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Data
@Alias("MemberDto")
public class MemberDto {
    private int id;
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",timezone = "Asia/Seoul")
    private Timestamp createdAt;
}

package data.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.Alias;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Data
@Alias("MemberDto")
public class MemberDto {
    private int id;
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",timezone = "Asia/Seoul")
    private Timestamp createdAt;
}

package data.service;

import data.dto.MemberDto;
import data.mapper.MemberMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MemberService {

    private MemberMapper memberMapper;

    public void insertMember(MemberDto dto){
        memberMapper.insertMember(dto);
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="data.mapper.MemberMapper">
    <insert id="insertMember" parameterType="MemberDto">
        INSERT INTO user (null, #{userId}, #{password}, #{email}, now())
    </insert>
</mapper>

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jake_dbschema
    username: root
    password: Rnjsgusdh0916!
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#  jpa:
#    hibernate:
#      ddl-auto: update
#    show-sql: true
#    properties:
#      hibernate:
#        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

#  security:
#    oauth2:
#      client:
#        registration:
#          google:
#            client-id:
#            client-secret:
#            scope:
#            redirect-uri: ""
#            client-name:
#        provider:
#          google:
#            authorization-uri:
#            token-uri:
#            user-info-uri:




server:
  port: 8080  # 여기에서 포트를 명시적으로 설정


#mybatis
mybatis:
  type-aliases-package: data.dto
  mapper-locations:
    - /mapper/**/*.xml

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.33'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.2'
    implementation group: 'io.awspring.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-aws', version: '2.4.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
//    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
//    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
//    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'

//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
//    implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'


}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

fixing bugs and trying to CRUD with Springboot and MySQL

Post the full stacktrace of the error in your question please. Nobody will be able to determine the error just by "Invalid bean definition error" there are dozens and dozens of different causes to this error.

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-09-01T12:48:04.922-07:00 ERROR 11033 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'memberMapper' defined in file [/Users/hyunohkwon/IdeaProjects/Jake/build/classes/java/main/data/mapper/MemberMapper.class]: Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String
at org.springframework.beans.factory.suppo

@Kwohyuno There are several problems (inconsistent versions, unnecessary configuration, etc.). It is better to start from a small working project and make small changes one by one. Then, if an error occurred, you may know which change caused the error. There is a project template for mybatis-spring-boot in this repo.
